# Swagger UI is not loading in VS 2019

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, swagger

I am trying to learn API development using Swagger.

My home VS 2019 has Version 16.11.25.

Org VS 2019 has version 16.11.21 (I tried updating it but couldn't do so due to some restrictions)

I chose the Web API template in my home VS, the default template had the Swagger packages installed. I simply clicked on execute, and it loaded the sample API with Swagger.
But when I tried to do the same with my Org VS, I chose the API template. It did not have swagger package pre installed.( I checked it twice). The sample test API loaded in JSON plain text format in Google Chrome. But I want to see the Swagger UI.

My Home VS 2019 gives me .net 5.0 framework but ORG VS is showing 3.1 framework(Although, the framework is 16.11.21)

I did the following things for Swagger-

Installed Swashuckle.AspNetCore(6.5.0)

I had initially loaded swashbuckle only but some functions were not recognised in the startup.cs file, so I had to load all other packages separately.

This is my startup.cs file -

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "CreateAPIPRactice", Version = "v1" });
    });
```

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "CreateAPIPRactice v1");

         c.RoutePrefix= "";

});
```

When I try to execute, the API still loads in The plain JSON format in Google Chrome.

EDIT:

I added swagger in the launch URL (launchsettings.json)

After this I can see the swagger homepage but I get a Failed to Load API, error code 500 Error

I navigated to this error and it says "asp.net core does not support multiple apps in the same app pool
Please assign the application /LM/W3SVC/ROOT/2/SWAGGER to a different IIS application pool"

but I am simply using the existing API template (WeatherForecast)

Another thing I noticed that initially my URL is localhost:44350/swagger
but then it redirects to
localhost:44350/index.html

the swagger is missing in URL, Though I can still see the swagger dashboard.

Comment: Have you check [Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) ? f you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.